# How to plot geo-data using matplotlib/python

Tags: python, geojson, json

I am trying to plot a polygone on python, using different libararies, but no one of these worked with me. 
I tried [vincent](https://github.com/wrobstory/vincent) ,[Shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) , .. and now matplotlib.
I don't wanna use softwares like [qgis](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/)

I used this example: 
http://geographika.co.uk/visualising-geojson-in-15-minutes

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
from descartes import PolygonPatch
import math
import urllib2
import simplejson

data = []
with open('file.json') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(json.loads(line))


def plotFeature(coordlist, myplot):
    #create a polygon geojson-like feature
    poly = {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": coordlist}
    patch = PolygonPatch(poly, fc='#6699cc', ec='#6699cc', alpha=0.5, zorder=2)
    #plot it on the graph
    myplot.add_patch(patch)


for coordlist in data['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates']:
    plotFeature(coordlist, myplot)

fig = pyplot.figure(1, figsize=(10, 4), dpi=180)
ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax.savefig('myplot.png')
```

External file "file.json"

```
var states = [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {"party": "Republican"},
    "geometry":

{
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
        [
            [
                -84.32281494140625,
                34.9895035675793
            ],
            [
                -84.29122924804688,
                35.21981940793435
            ],
            [
                -84.24041748046875,
                35.25459097465022
            ],
            [
                -84.22531127929688,
                35.266925688950074
            ],
            [
                -84.20745849609375,
                35.26580442886754
            ],
            [
                -84.19921875,
                35.24674063355999
            ],
            [
                -84.16213989257812,
                35.24113278166642
            ],
            [
                -84.12368774414062,
                35.24898366572645
            ],
            [
                -84.09072875976562,
                35.24898366572645
            ],
            [
                -84.08798217773438,
                35.264683153268116
            ],
            [
                -84.04266357421875,
                35.27701633139884
            ],
            [
                -84.03030395507812,
                35.291589484566124
            ],
            [
                -84.0234375,
                35.306160014550784
            ],
            [
                -84.03305053710936,
                35.32745068492882
            ],
            [
                -84.03579711914062,
                35.34313496028189
            ],
            [
                -84.03579711914062,
                35.348735749472546
            ],
            [
                -84.01657104492188,
                35.35545618392078
            ],
            [
                -84.01107788085938,
                35.37337460834958
            ],
            [
                -84.00970458984374,
                35.39128905521763
            ],
            [
                -84.01931762695312,
                35.41479572901859
            ],
            [
                -84.00283813476562,
                35.429344044107154
            ],
            [
                -83.93692016601562,
                35.47409160773029
            ],
            [
                -83.91220092773438,
                35.47632833265728
            ],
            [
                -83.88885498046875,
                35.504282143299655
            ],
            [
                -83.88473510742186,
                35.516578738902936
            ],
            [
                -83.8751220703125,
                35.52104976129943
            ],
            [
                -83.85314941406249,
                35.52104976129943
            ],
            [
                -83.82843017578125,
                35.52104976129943
            ],
            [
                -83.8092041015625,
                35.53446133418443
            ],
            [
                -83.80233764648438,
                35.54116627999813
            ],
            [
                -83.76800537109374,
                35.56239491058853
            ],
            [
                -83.7432861328125,
                35.56239491058853
            ],
            [
                -83.71994018554688,
                35.56239491058853
            ],
            [
                -83.67050170898438,
                35.569097520776054
            ],
            [
                -83.6334228515625,
                35.570214567965984
            ],
            [
                -83.61007690429688,
                35.576916524038616
            ],
            [
                -83.59634399414061,
                35.574682600980914
            ],
            [
                -83.5894775390625,
                35.55904339525896
            ],
            [
                -83.55239868164062,
                35.56574628576276
            ],
            [
                -83.49746704101562,
                35.563512051219696
            ],
            [
                -83.47000122070312,
                35.586968406786475
            ],
            [
                -83.4466552734375,
                35.60818490437746
            ],
            [
                -83.37936401367188,
                35.63609277863135
            ],
            [
                -83.35739135742188,
                35.65618041632016
            ],
            [
                -83.32305908203124,
                35.66622234103479
            ],
            [
                -83.3148193359375,
                35.65394870599763
            ],
            [
                -83.29971313476561,
                35.660643649881614
            ],
            [
                -83.28598022460938,
                35.67180064238771
            ],
            [
                -83.26126098632811,
                35.6907639509368
            ],
            [
                -83.25714111328125,
                35.69968630125201
            ],
            [
                -83.25576782226562,
                35.715298012125295
            ],
            [
                -83.23516845703125,
                35.72310272092263
            ],
            [
                -83.19808959960936,
                35.72756221127198
            ],
            [
                -83.16238403320312,
                35.753199435570316
            ],
            [
                -83.15826416015625,
                35.76322914549896
            ],
            [
                -83.10333251953125,
                35.76991491635478
            ],
            [
                -83.08685302734375,
                35.7843988251953
            ],
            [
                -83.0511474609375,
                35.787740890986576
            ],
            [
                -83.01681518554688,
                35.78328477203738
            ],
            [
                -83.001708984375,
                35.77882840327371
            ],
            [
                -82.96737670898438,
                35.793310688351724
            ],
            [
                -82.94540405273438,
                35.820040281161
            ],
            [
                -82.9193115234375,
                35.85121343450061
            ],
            [
                -82.9083251953125,
                35.86902116501695
            ],
            [
                -82.90557861328125,
                35.87792352995116
            ],
            [
                -82.91244506835938,
                35.92353244718235
            ],
            [
                -82.88360595703125,
                35.94688293218141
            ],
            [
                -82.85614013671875,
                35.951329861522666
            ],
            [
                -82.8424072265625,
                35.94243575255426
            ],
            [
                -82.825927734375,
                35.92464453144099
            ],
            [
                -82.80670166015625,
                35.927980690382704
            ],
            [
                -82.80532836914062,
                35.94243575255426
            ],
            [
                -82.77923583984375,
                35.97356075349624
            ],
            [
                -82.78060913085938,
                35.99245209055831
            ],
            [
                -82.76138305664062,
                36.00356252895066
            ],
            [
                -82.69546508789062,
                36.04465753921525
            ],
            [
                -82.64465332031249,
                36.060201412392914
            ],
            [
                -82.61306762695312,
                36.060201412392914
            ],
            [
                -82.60620117187499,
                36.033552893400376
            ],
            [
                -82.60620117187499,
                35.991340960635405
            ],
            [
                -82.60620117187499,
                35.97911749857497
            ],
            [
                -82.5787353515625,
                35.96133453736691
            ],
            [
                -82.5677490234375,
                35.951329861522666
            ],
            [
                -82.53067016601562,
                35.97244935753683
            ],
            [
                -82.46475219726562,
                36.006895355244666
            ],
            [
                -82.41668701171875,
                36.070192281208456
            ],
            [
                -82.37960815429686,
                36.10126686921446
            ],
            [
                -82.35488891601562,
                36.117908916563685
            ],
            [
                -82.34115600585936,
                36.113471382052175
            ],
            [
                -82.29583740234375,
                36.13343831245866
            ],
            [
                -82.26287841796874,
                36.13565654678543
            ],
            [
                -82.23403930664062,
                36.13565654678543
            ],
            [
                -82.2216796875,
                36.154509006695
            ],
            [
                -82.20382690429688,
                36.15561783381855
            ],
            [
                -82.19009399414062,
                36.144528857027744
            ],
            [
                -82.15438842773438,
                36.15007354140755
            ],
            [
                -82.14065551757812,
                36.134547437460064
            ],
            [
                -82.1337890625,
                36.116799556445024
            ],
            [
                -82.12142944335938,
                36.10570509327921
            ],
            [
                -82.08984375,
                36.10792411128649
            ],
            [
                -82.05276489257811,
                36.12678323326429
            ],
            [
                -82.03628540039062,
                36.12900165569652
            ],
            [
                -81.91268920898438,
                36.29409768373033
            ],
            [
                -81.89071655273438,
                36.30959215409138
            ],
            [
                -81.86325073242188,
                36.33504067209607
            ],
            [
                -81.83029174804688,
                36.34499652561904
            ],
            [
                -81.80145263671875,
                36.35605709240176
            ],
            [
                -81.77947998046874,
                36.34610265300638
            ],
            [
                -81.76162719726562,
                36.33835943134047
            ],
            [
                -81.73690795898438,
                36.33835943134047
            ],
            [
                -81.71905517578125,
                36.33835943134047
            ],
            [
                -81.70669555664062,
                36.33504067209607
            ],
            [
                -81.70669555664062,
                36.342784223707234
            ],
            [
                -81.72317504882812,
                36.357163062654365
            ],
            [
                -81.73278808593749,
                36.379279167407965
            ],
            [
                -81.73690795898438,
                36.40028364332352
            ],
            [
                -81.73690795898438,
                36.41354670392876
            ],
            [
                -81.72454833984374,
                36.423492513472326
            ],
            [
                -81.71768188476562,
                36.445589751779174
            ],
            [
                -81.69845581054688,
                36.47541104282962
            ],
            [
                -81.69845581054688,
                36.51073994146672
            ],
            [
                -81.705322265625,
                36.53060536411363
            ],
            [
                -81.69158935546875,
                36.55929085774001
            ],
            [
                -81.68060302734375,
                36.56480607840351
            ],
            [
                -81.68197631835938,
                36.58686302344181
            ],
            [
                -81.04202270507812,
                36.56370306576917
            ],
            [
                -80.74264526367186,
                36.561496993252575
            ],
            [
                -79.89120483398438,
                36.54053616262899
            ],
            [
                -78.68408203124999,
                36.53943280355122
            ],
            [
                -77.88345336914062,
                36.54053616262899
            ],
            [
                -76.91665649414062,
                36.54163950596125
            ],
            [
                -76.91665649414062,
                36.55046568575947
            ],
            [
                -76.31103515625,
                36.551568887374
            ],
            [
                -75.79605102539062,
                36.54936246839778
            ],
            [
                -75.6298828125,
                36.07574221562703
            ],
            [
                -75.4925537109375,
                35.82226734114509
            ],
            [
                -75.3936767578125,
                35.639441068973916
            ],
            [
                -75.41015624999999,
                35.43829554739668
            ],
            [
                -75.43212890625,
                35.263561862152095
            ],
            [
                -75.487060546875,
                35.18727767598896
            ],
            [
                -75.5914306640625,
                35.17380831799959
            ],
            [
                -75.9210205078125,
                35.04798673426734
            ],
            [
                -76.17919921875,
                34.867904962568744
            ],
            [
                -76.41540527343749,
                34.62868797377061
            ],
            [
                -76.4593505859375,
                34.57442951865274
            ],
            [
                -76.53076171875,
                34.53371242139567
            ],
            [
                -76.5911865234375,
                34.551811369170494
            ],
            [
                -76.651611328125,
                34.615126683462194
            ],
            [
                -76.761474609375,
                34.63320791137959
            ],
            [
                -77.069091796875,
                34.59704151614417
            ],
            [
                -77.376708984375,
                34.45674800347809
            ],
            [
                -77.5909423828125,
                34.3207552752374
            ],
            [
                -77.8326416015625,
                33.97980872872457
            ],
            [
                -77.9150390625,
                33.80197351806589
            ],
            [
                -77.9754638671875,
                33.73804486328907
            ],
            [
                -78.11279296875,
                33.8521697014074
            ],
            [
                -78.2830810546875,
                33.8521697014074
            ],
            [
                -78.4808349609375,
                33.815666308702774
            ],
            [
                -79.6728515625,
                34.8047829195724
            ],
            [
                -80.782470703125,
                34.836349990763864
            ],
            [
                -80.782470703125,
                34.91746688928252
            ],
            [
                -80.9307861328125,
                35.092945313732635
            ],
            [
                -81.0516357421875,
                35.02999636902566
            ],
            [
                -81.0516357421875,
                35.05248370662468
            ],
            [
                -81.0516357421875,
                35.137879119634185
            ],
            [
                -82.3150634765625,
                35.19625600786368
            ],
            [
                -82.3590087890625,
                35.19625600786368
            ],
            [
                -82.40295410156249,
                35.22318504970181
            ],
            [
                -82.4688720703125,
                35.16931803601131
            ],
            [
                -82.6885986328125,
                35.1154153142536
            ],
            [
                -82.781982421875,
                35.06147690849717
            ],
            [
                -83.1060791015625,
                35.003003395276714
            ],
            [
                -83.616943359375,
                34.99850370014629
            ],
            [
                -84.05639648437499,
                34.985003130171066
            ],
            [
                -84.22119140625,
                34.985003130171066
            ],
            [
                -84.32281494140625,
                34.9895035675793
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                -75.69030761718749,
                35.74205383068037
            ],
            [
                -75.5914306640625,
                35.74205383068037
            ],
            [
                -75.5419921875,
                35.585851593232356
            ],
            [
                -75.56396484375,
                35.32633026307483
            ],
            [
                -75.69030761718749,
                35.285984736065735
            ],
            [
                -75.970458984375,
                35.16482750605027
            ],
            [
                -76.2066650390625,
                34.994003757575776
            ],
            [
                -76.300048828125,
                35.02999636902566
            ],
            [
                -76.409912109375,
                35.07946034047981
            ],
            [
                -76.5252685546875,
                35.10642805736423
            ],
            [
                -76.4208984375,
                35.25907654252574
            ],
            [
                -76.3385009765625,
                35.294952147406576
            ],
            [
                -76.0858154296875,
                35.29943548054543
            ],
            [
                -75.948486328125,
                35.44277092585766
            ],
            [
                -75.8660888671875,
                35.53669637839501
            ],
            [
                -75.772705078125,
                35.567980458012094
            ],
            [
                -75.706787109375,
                35.634976650677295
            ],
            [
                -75.706787109375,
                35.74205383068037
            ],
            [
                -75.69030761718749,
                35.74205383068037
            ]
        ]
    ]
} } ]
```

But it doesn't seem to work out. I need to plot these coordinates with a map on background. Any example, library, tutorial to recommend ?

Answer (score 15):

You cannot apply this particular example without understanding the JSON format: your external file "file.json" is not an .json file

A correct format would be (without `var states = [`:)

```
{
"type": "Feature",
"properties": {"party": "Republican"},
"geometry":
{
"type": "Polygon",
"coordinates": [
    [
        [
            -84.32281494140625,
            34.9895035675793
 ....
 } }
```

To process this file, you can use the standard [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module or directly the [geojson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geojson/1.0.6) module instead of the [simplejson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/) module, deprecated since Python 2.6 (for Python versions < 2.6)

Read and parse the file:

```
import json # or import geojson
with open("file.json") as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file) # or geojson.load(json_file)
```

The result is a classic Python dictionary with the keys:

```
print json_data.keys()
[u'geometry', u'type', u'properties']
```

The geometry is :

```
poly = json_data['geometry']
print poly
{u'type': u'Polygon', u'coordinates': [[[-84.32281494140625, 34.989503567579298], [-84.291229248046875, 35.219819407934352], ..., [-75.690307617187486, 35.742053830680369]]]}
```

This result is directly usable with [Descartes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/descartes/1.0.1) and you don't need `poly = {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": coordlist}`

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
 from descartes import PolygonPatch
 BLUE = '#6699cc'
 fig = plt.figure() 
 ax = fig.gca() 
 ax.add_patch(PolygonPatch(poly, fc=BLUE, ec=BLUE, alpha=0.5, zorder=2 ))
 ax.axis('scaled')
 plt.show()
```

[image]

But you can also use the coordinates to plot the outer ring of the polygon

```
coords = json_data['geometry']['coordinates']
print coords
[[[-84.32281494140625, 34.989503567579298], [-84.291229248046875, 35.219819407934352],....[-75.690307617187486, 35.742053830680369]]]
 x = [i for i,j in coords[0]]
 y = [j for i,j in coords[0]]
 ax = fig.gca() 
 ax.plot(x,y)
 ax.axis('scaled')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The code looks good, but

1. Your file.json file isn't JSON, it's Javascript, and that's not the same thing.
2. There is no "features" object in the data, so data['features'] will fail even if the JSON was parsed.

Once you fix the data and your access to it, you should get a plot.