# Plot shapefile with matplotlib

Tags: shapefile, matplotlib

I am trying to read a shapefile and plot it using matplotlib. Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import shapefile   

shpFilePath = "D:\test.shp"  
listx=[]
listy=[]
test = shapefile.Reader(shpFilePath)
for sr in test.shapeRecords():
    for xNew,yNew in sr.shape.points:
        listx.append(xNew)
        listy.append(yNew)
plt.plot(listx,listy)
plt.show()
```

However, i get lines connecting my polygons. How can I draw the polygons such that they are the way in the shapefile. Here are screenshots of the plot and the shapefile when it is opened with ArcGIS.[image: Generated By Code] [image: Actual File]

Comment: Not familiar with the shapefile reader, however I can tell that you are just appending all the points in the file to one big list without separating each shape into its component parts. You need a big list of shapes to which you append each shapes points

Comment: Right. Have to find a way to separate the shapes. But that is what I am unable to do at the moment.

Comment: @DanPatterson Can you specify how to plot multiple shapes in the same figure after I manage to separate the shapes? If i use plt.plot(listx,listy) for every shape, it keeps generating a new figure every time, instead of using the same figure.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I will leave it to you how to collect the shapes but this is the principle

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as p  #contains both numpy and pyplot
x1 = [-1,-1,10,10,-1]; y1 = [-1,10,10,-1,-1]
x2 = [21,21,29,29,21]; y2 = [21,29,29,21,21]
shapes = [[x1,y1],[x2,y2]]
for shape in shapes:
  x,y = shape
  p.plot(x,y)
p.show()
```

Comment: oh.. wonder how i missed that. i do get the shapes printed in different colors though. Will have to fix that :)

Comment: how to get or isolate the different shapes?

Answer (score 18):

For future references, here is the solution I have came to after following the advices above.

```
import shapefile as shp  # Requires the pyshp package
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sf = shp.Reader("test.shp")

plt.figure()
for shape in sf.shapeRecords():
    x = [i[0] for i in shape.shape.points[:]]
    y = [i[1] for i in shape.shape.points[:]]
    plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

The resulting figure will be very colorful, but then, you just need to adjust the plot keywords.

Comment: I know this might be redundant information, but for those not yet familiar with the subject it would have been useful to say that `import shapefile` refers to the `pyshp` package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyshp

Comment: This is not ok when you have a bunch of islands, as these points will be connected by lines to points on the mainland, creating something similar to what the OP posted.

Comment: @FaCoffee, you are right. My answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/309780/126618 should address this.

Answer (score 11):

You need to use matplotlib [paths](http://matplotlib.org/api/path_api.html) and [patches](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html) and there is a Python module dedicated to plot polygons from shapefiles using these functions [Descartes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/descartes/1.0.1).

As Pyshp (shapefile) has the [**geo_interface**](https://gist.github.com/sgillies/2217756) ([New **geo_interface** for PyShp](http://geospatialpython.com/2013/05/new-geointerface-for-pyshp.html)) convention, you can use it.

```py
polys  = shapefile.Reader("polygon")
# first polygon
poly = polys.iterShapes().next().__geo_interface__
print poly
{'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': (((151116.87238259654, 135890.8706318218), (153492.19971554304, 134793.3055883224), (153934.50204650551, 133892.31935858406), (152623.97662143156, 131811.86024627919), (150903.91200102202, 130894.49244872745), (149347.66305874675, 132991.33312884573), (149151.08424498566, 134383.76639298678), (151116.87238259654, 135890.8706318218)),)}
```

The result is the GeoJSON representation of the geometry and you can use the solution of [How to plot geo-data using matplotlib/python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93136/how-to-plot-geo-data-using-matplotlib-python/93201#93201)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from descartes import PolygonPatch
BLUE = '#6699cc'
fig = plt.figure() 
ax = fig.gca() 
ax.add_patch(PolygonPatch(poly, fc=BLUE, ec=BLUE, alpha=0.5, zorder=2 ))
ax.axis('scaled')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That's really helpful, but can you do this in a for loop if you have multiple polygons to plot?

Comment: Yes without problem

Comment: I noticed that the `descartes` solution does not work if you try and plot two different shapefiles on two adjacent subplots using `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(15, 8))` and then `ax[0].add_patch(PolygonPatch(poly_geo, fc='#d3d3d3', ec='#000000', alpha=0, zorder=5))` and `ax[1].add_patch(PolygonPatch(poly_geo, fc='#d3d3d3', ec='#000000', alpha=0, zorder=5))`. The result is an empty image. Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to ldocao answer, and responding to FaCoffee question. When you have isolated islands and they are part of the same feature, you can try next:

```
import shapefile as shp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sf = shp.Reader("test.shp")

plt.figure()
for shape in sf.shapeRecords():
    for i in range(len(shape.shape.parts)):
        i_start = shape.shape.parts[i]
        if i==len(shape.shape.parts)-1:
            i_end = len(shape.shape.points)
        else:
            i_end = shape.shape.parts[i+1]
        x = [i[0] for i in shape.shape.points[i_start:i_end]]
        y = [i[1] for i in shape.shape.points[i_start:i_end]]
        plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

This makes it work for me. The propertie "parts" of a shape returns the starting indexes of differents geometries inside a feature.

Answer (score 4):

The most simple answer is using geopandas itself.

```
import geopandas as gpd
df=gpd.read_file("filename.shp")
df.plot()
```

Answer (score 3):

It can be done using either geopandas or pyshp as discussed in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202839/plotting-large-shapefiles-with-matplotlib/266675#266675). Geopandas use matplotlib at its backend for plotting.

Answer (score 3):

Still, in one shapefile shape, there may be multiple parts. This will plot each part within one shape, separately.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import shapefile
import numpy as np

this_shapefile = shapefile.Reader(map_file_base) # whichever file
shape = this_shapefile.shape(i) # whichever shape
points = np.array(shape.points)

intervals = list(shape.parts) + [len(shape.points)]

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_aspect(1)

for (i, j) in zip(intervals[:-1], intervals[1:]):
    ax.plot(*zip(*points[i:j]))
```