# Plotting Shapely Multipolygon using Matplotlib

Tags: python, shapely, matplotlib

I have few polygons or boxes. Ones intersect each other but some are isolated. For example I have free figures:

```
import shapely.geometry as sg
import shapely.ops as so
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
r1 = sg.Polygon([(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0),(0,0)])
r2 = sg.box(0.5,0.5,1.5,1.5)
r3 = sg.box(4,4,5,5)
```

First two are intersected and r3 is on some distance from them. I unite them via cascaded_union:

```
new_shape = so.cascaded_union([r1, r2, r3])
```

Then I try to plot it (one united figure of r1 and r2 and  one distanced box r3)

```
xs, ys = new_shape.exterior.xy
fig, axs = plt.subplots()
axs.fill(xs, ys, alpha=0.5, fc='r', ec='none')
plt.show()
```

Instead of plot I receive an `AttributeError: 'MultiPolygon' object has no attribute 'exterior'.`
Is there a pythonic way to display a multipolygon  or to iterate through it and draw its parts?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Shapely `Polygon` object has attribute `exterior`. Shapely `MultiPolygon` object has `Polygon` object sequence. You should iterate over those polygons. You can do that using attribute `geoms` of `MultiPolygon`.

Use this way:

```
import shapely.geometry as sg
import shapely.ops as so
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r1 = sg.Polygon([(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0),(0,0)])
r2 = sg.box(0.5,0.5,1.5,1.5)
r3 = sg.box(4,4,5,5)

new_shape = so.unary_union([r1, r2, r3])
fig, axs = plt.subplots()
axs.set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')

for geom in new_shape.geoms:    
    xs, ys = geom.exterior.xy    
    axs.fill(xs, ys, alpha=0.5, fc='r', ec='none')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `cascaded_union` is deprecated. See [here](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.cascaded_union).

Answer (score 13):

An alternative, shorter way of plotting using @Kadir Şahbaz's answer:

**Edit**: Per @petezurich's comment, `cascaded_union` is superseded by `unary_union` as of 1.8.0

```
new_shape = so.unary_union([r1, r2, r3])

# Plot each polygon shape directly
for geom in new_shape.geoms:
    plt.plot(*geom.exterior.xy)

# Set (current) axis to be equal before showing plot
plt.gca().axis("equal")
plt.show()
```

Comment: `cascaded_union` is deprecated. See [here](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.cascaded_union).

Answer (score 6):

Look at [Plot shapefile with islands with matplotlib](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/340561/2581) for example.

As with polygons you can use matplotlib [paths](http://matplotlib.org/api/path_api.html) and [patches](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html) and there is a Python module dedicated to plot polygons from shapefiles using these functions [Descartes](https://pypi.org/project/descartes/).

```
new_shape= so.unary_union([r1, r2, r3])
from descartes import PolygonPatch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
BLUE = '#6699cc'
GRAY = '#999999'
fig = plt.figure() 
ax = fig.gca() 
ax.add_patch(PolygonPatch(new_shape, fc=GRAY, ec=BLUE, alpha=0.5, zorder=2 ))
ax.axis('scaled')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use [GeoPandas'](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.plot.html) `.plot()` function:

```
import shapely.geometry as sg
import shapely.ops as so
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd

r1 = sg.Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0)])
r2 = sg.box(0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 1.5)
r3 = sg.box(4, 4, 5, 5)

new_shape = so.cascaded_union([r1, r2, r3])
gpd.GeoSeries(new_shape).plot()
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is the easiest solution, I'd wager.