# How to map geoJSON polygon from a url request in python

Tags: python, polygon, geojson, api, json

Using Python I have loaded json data from the url http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/floods and have found that the flood areas encoded as geoJSON polygons are displayed as url links.

What code do I use to map these polygons in python?

Here is additional information on the API and layers:
http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/doc/reference#api-structure

Comment: What sort of map do you want?

Comment: Just a plain basemap for now, of the UK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examining the first feature of the json data file:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/floods')
data = r.json()
# the result is directly a dictionary and if we examine the keys
data.keys()
[u'@context', u'meta', u'items']
# look at the first item
data['items'][0]
{u'severityLevel': 3, u'isTidal': False, u'description': u'Upper Bristol Avon Area', u'timeSeverityChanged': u'2016-02-05T17:04:00', u'eaRegionName': u'South West', u'floodAreaID': u'112WAFTUBA', u'timeMessageChanged': u'2016-02-17T09:48:00', u'floodArea': {u'county': u'Wiltshire', u'riverOrSea': u'Bristol River Avon', u'@id': u'http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/floodAreas/112WAFTUBA', u'polygon': u'http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/floodAreas/112WAFTUBA/polygon', u'notation': u'112WAFTUBA'}, u'timeRaised': u'2016-02-17T09:48:00', u'message': u'Up to 20 mm of rain is forecast to fall on Wednesday 17th February which is expected to raise river levels as rain falls on saturated ground. River levels on the Tetbury Avon at Brokenborough, Sherston Avon at Fosseway, River Avon at Great Somerford and Dauntsey Brook at Dauntsey are currently stable but should rise in response to Wednesday\u2019s rain. We will continue to monitor the situation and update this message as the situation changes.', u'@id': u'http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/floods/95882', u'eaAreaName': u'North Wessex', u'severity': u'Flood Alert'}
```

We can see that the geometry is an url (`u'polygon': u'http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/floodAreas/112WAFTUBA/polygon'`)

```
print data['items'][0]['floodArea']['polygon']
http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/floodAreas/112WAFTUBA/polygon
# name of the river
print data['items'][0]['floodArea']['riverOrSea']
Bristol River Avon
# County
print data['items'][0]['floodArea']['county']
Wiltshire
```

Therefore, the geometry

```
r2 = requests.get(data['items'][0]['floodArea']['polygon'])
geom = r2.json()
print geom.keys()
[u'crs', u'type', u'features']
print geom['type']
FeatureCollection
print geom['crs']
{u'type': u'name', u'properties': {u'name': u'urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84'}}
```

But this is not a valid GeoJSON because the features are a list of dictionaries and not a dictionary of dictionaries (= first element of the list)

```
print geom['features'][0]['properties']
{u'FWIS_CODE': u'112WAFTUBA', u'W_DESCRIP': None, u'W_FWA_NAME': None, u'AREA': u'North Wessex', u'REGION': u'South West Region', u'W_AFON': None, u'COUNTY': u'Wiltshire', u'FWD_TACODE': u'112WAFTUBA', u'E_QDIAL': u'04423', u'W_REGION': u'DG Lloegr', u'DESCRIP': u'Upper River Avon and tributaries including Malmesbury and Chippenham', u'RIVER_SEA': u'Bristol River Avon', u'FWA_NAME': u'Upper Bristol Avon Area', u'W_QDIAL': None}
# and 
print geom['features'][0]['geometry']['type']
MultiPolygon
# GeoJSON geometry =  geom['features'][0]['geometry'] (very long)
```

Result (in red)

[image]

Apply the same procedure for all other items. In place of request, you can use urllib, urllib2 or others...

Comment: That's fantastic thank you! I am however still struggling to map the flood. I had a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93136/how-to-plot-geo-data-using-matplotlib-python but the data.keys() were different to the ones here, so that didn't work. Yours looks great though, how did you achieve that?

Comment: Simply by examining the first json file and searching for geometry.